# How to deserialize DynamoDB Map type in Lambda handler

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have a simple POJO:

```
public class MyClass {
    public String id;
    public String name;
}
```

I want to serialize it to JSON equivalent to the format an AWS Lambda handler for DynamoDB events would get for en embedded document of DynamoDB type [`Map`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes):

```
M: { 
    id= { S: "abc123", },
    name= { S: "whatever", },
}
```

And even more imporantly, I want to deserialize it from the JSON my Lambda function receives for every insert. The only examples I can find are very simple ones. None of them includes dealing with DynamoDB Maps in events inside of a Lambda handler.

I wonder if I have to write a serializer by hand or if there's something in the SDK I haven't found yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map your POJO to an instance of `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue` and then serialize/deserialize it with `GSON`.

This is how to [get started with Gson](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html).

Below is an example of how to manipulate AttributeValue with Gson.

```
AttributeValue av1 = new AttributeValue("abc123");
AttributeValue av2 = new AttributeValue("whatever");
AttributeValue avM = new AttributeValue();
Map<String, AttributeValue> m = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
m.put("id", av1);
m.put("name", av2);
avM.setM(m);
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(avM));
// {"m":{"name":{"s":"whatever"},"id":{"s":"abc123"}}}

Map<String, Object> simpleMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
simpleMap.put("id", "abc123");
simpleMap.put("name", "whatever");
AttributeValue avM2 = new AttributeValue().withM(InternalUtils.fromSimpleMap(simpleMap));
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(avM2));
// {"m":{"name":{"s":"whatever"},"id":{"s":"abc123"}}}

String jsonStr = new Gson().toJson(avM2);
AttributeValue avM3 = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, AttributeValue.class);
System.out.println(avM3.getM().get("id").getS());
// abc123
System.out.println(avM3.getM().get("name").getS());
// whatever
```

If you are getting started with Lambda and DynamoDB with Java, I would suggest you to take a look at the [Secure Pet Store](https://github.com/awslabs/api-gateway-secure-pet-store).

Comment: Could you provide an example please? A link would be fine I guess.

Comment: You can also use the included Jackson class if you don't want to depend on Gson: ObjectWriter writer = Jackson.getObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL).writer();

Comment: Thanks! I wish there was a less cumbersome way, but this will do the trick for now.